# why doesn’t my very simple input() code work?

Tags: python, simple-form

```
print("what pass")
pass = input()
print(pass + " password")
```

I am certain this should work...
Please update me in the comments
I am new to python coding and coding in general

Comment: `pass` is a keyword in python, you can't use it as a variable name

Answer (score 4):

In Python, `pass` is a [keyword (aka reserved word)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).  Change it to, say `pwd` and it should work.

> 2.3.1. Keywords
> The following identifiers are used as reserved words, or keywords of the language, and cannot be used as ordinary identifiers. They must be spelled exactly as written here:

```
False      await      else       import     pass
None       break      except     in         raise
True       class      finally    is         return
and        continue   for        lambda     try
as         def        from       nonlocal   while
assert     del        global     not        with
async      elif       if         or         yield
```